# image.new() is not working with parameter "color"

Tags: python, image

as per 2.82a API, the color parameter is not accepted by image.new()

[image]
[image]

Comment: HI. It would be helpful if you actually showed the command you typed in that produced the error. Thanks.

Comment: `bpy.ops.image.new(color=(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0))` works in 2.81, 2.82 and 2.83 just like the API docs say. Your stack trace looks like you've tried to create a new object based on [BlendDataImage](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataImages.html#bpy.types.BlendDataImages.new).

Answer (score 1):

a work around with `#bpy.data.images["texture"].generated_color = (1, 1, 1, 1)` in the next line would achieve the same.